# Getting type mismatch error when setting Worksheet.Name to a cell.value in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have written the following code to create worksheet with names same as the names in first column of Sheet1
I am getting a TypeError when trying to set the name on the new worksheet but don't know why. Can someone help?

```
Sub CreateWorkSheets()
    '
    ' Macro5 Macro
    '
    '
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(1)
    For Each cell In r
        Dim aa As String

        Dim newSheet As Worksheet
        Set newSheet = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
        strTemp = cell.Value
        newSheet.Name = strTemp // Error Here
    Next cell
End Sub
```

I tried the following code as well and that doesn't work either even though strValue is valid

```
Sub Test1()

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Dim x As Integer
' Set numrows = number of rows of data.
NumRows = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).rows.Count
' Select cell a1.
Range("A2").Select

' Establish "For" loop to loop "numrows" number of times.
For x = 1 To NumRows
    Dim newSheet As Worksheet
    Set newSheet = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value = "A" + Trim(Str(x))
    strValue = "A" + Trim(Str(x))

    newSheet.Name = Str(Sheets("Sheet1").Range(strValue).Value)
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What I do normally when I have this task is to use "ActiveSheet.Name"

Comment: You're probably reaching blank cells because you're looping through every cell in column A.

Comment: I tried using ActiveSheet.Name and that doesn't work either. Also, I am stepping through the code and I can see that strTemp is valid. For example if I add the line  Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = strValue, that works and the proper name shows up. If I was reaching blank cells, I would at least get some worksheets added before the code failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently because you set:

```
Set r = Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(1)
```

It set the cell object to column $A:$A instead of $A$1 like you would think. I put this in the immediate window when I ran into the "cell.value" line:

```
?cell.Address
$A:$A
```

You should avoid using an entire column to do what you're trying to do and I would highly recommend you add these keywords to the top of your module:

```
Option Explicit
```

This will check your code a little more thoroughly and help you avoid unwanted errors.

To fix this, you can get the exact range you need and I recommend you declare every variable so it stays a specific type.

Something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateWorkSheets()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim tempSh As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim strTemp As String

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set r = sh.Range(sh.Cells(1, 1), sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))

    For Each cell In r
        Set tempSh = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
        strTemp = cell.Value
        tempSh.Name = strTemp '// no more error
    Next cell
End Sub
```